# How to detect **ONLY** illegal characters, and not other language fonts, such as greek, in PHP

Tags: php, validation, preg-replace

My purpose is to get the data from user and then insert into database, but the data could be written in either greek or english, i used **preg_replace** but greek fonts are ruled out.

Comment: what is an *illegal* character?

Comment: hmmm anything not letter or digit such as ' . , " ` @ # $ % ^ & * - + etc....

Comment: What did you use when the greek "fonts" (is it font or characters) were ruled out?

Comment: `code`preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $uname)`code` and `code`preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9Α-Ωα-ω]/", "", $uname)`code` the second one rules out most of greek fonts